# Search service crawl generates thousands of unexpected log messages

Tags: search

Our search application *appears* to be working fine.  Crawls do succeed, queries return, and general usage appears to be unaffected.

However, with every full crawl, we get thousands of the following message appearing in the logs:

```
01-15-2014 02:00:57.88    NodeRunnerContent1-7a4b7212-aa0    (0x0D10)    0x06CC    Search    Content Processing    ajyhd    Unexpected    DisplayAuthorEvaluator : (IStringField)aliasField == null
```

Many google attempts have resulted in literally zero results, so I know this is a long shot.  Does anyone have any ideas even of where I might look for further diagnosis?

(This is Sharepoint 2013, new farm, but with some content migrated from 2010)

Comment: i dont know much to answer but this should put you into the right direction, its todo with the sql database... there is an aliasField that is null within the content database that is possible that wasnt used in 2010 but is in 2013

Answer (score 1):

It's been some time, yet just for the record as sometimes we deal with unupdated farms. There is an hotfix related to this issue:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2899469

- When you crawl a SharePoint 2013 site, the Author property of a Word document cannot be crawled, and the crawled property DisplayAuthor is not updated. Additionally, an error is logged in the ULS logs.